# aligning top and bottom of 2 TextViews to an ImageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android-layout

I want to achieve the following layout:

[image]

For this purpose I use a RelativeLayout and set the attributes accordingly:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_top_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_right"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/icon"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/icon"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But this is what I get:

[image]

The label aligns perfectly to the top of the icon.
The value also is below the label and aligned to the left of the label but it won't align to the bottom of the icon.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this TextView:

```
<TextView android:id="@id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/icon"
/>
```

Remove `android:layout_below="@id/label"`, otherwise it will be placed under the first one.

So simply change it to

```
<TextView android:id="@id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/icon"
/>
```

Comment: Great, that works, i didn't know that there is some precedence or exclusion of rules.